# When to use self for Ruby Class

Tags: ruby

Can somebody help me distinguish When we create methods inside `class << self` block and when we define normal methods.

I saw somewhere code like this, but I don't know concisely the use cases of them

```
class Foo
  def initialize
  end

  def bar
  end

  class << self
    def foobar
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It depends on whether you want an instance method or a class method. Simple as that.

Comment: Personally, I prefer `def self.foobar` to nesting it within a `class << self`

Comment: See, for example, [Understanding class methods versus instance methods in Ruby](https://culttt.com/2015/06/10/understanding-class-methods-verses-instance-methods-in-ruby/) (yes, the correct spelling of "verses" is "versus"... "verses" are parts of a song or poem haha).

Comment: @lurker, "vursus" is also frequently confused with "Versas", much Nissan's dismay. btw, on SO, laughing at your own joke is bad form.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it wasn't a joke. My "haha" was just a general expression of levity.

Comment: Please consider selecting the answer you found most helpful (if any were helpful).

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland. We have answers, but those answers don't focus on what I asked, the USE CASES. I understand them in syntax, but I'm confused about the use cases of them. I found the comment of Lurker is best match for me. And I can only vote up that comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods defined right inside a `class` block are **instance methods**:

```
class Foo
  def bar
  end
end
```

Methods defined within `class << self` inside a `class` block are **class methods**:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    def baz
    end
  end
end
```

Instance methods become available to any instance of a given class:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.bar
```

Whereas class methods can be called directly on the class:

```
Foo.baz
```

Attempting to call instance methods on the class or vice versa results in an error:

```
Foo.bar #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `bar' for Foo:Class
foo.baz #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `baz' for #<Foo:0x00007ffe20055a20>
```

Another way to define class methods is by prefixing the method name with `self.`:

```
class Foo
  def self.baz
  end
end
```

You could also define them outside the `class` block, although this is rarely seen:

```
def Foo.baz
end
```

Or likewise:

```
class << Foo
  def baz
  end
end
```

Note that defining methods this way is not limited to classes. You can add methods to arbitrary objects, e.g.:

```
o = Object.new

def o.hello
  "hello from o"
end

o.hello
#=> "hello from o"
```

Or via:

```
class << o
  def hello
    "hello from o"
  end
end
```

Internally, these methods are added to the object's *singleton class*. It's a special purpose class to hold methods for just that instance:

```
o.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
#=> [:hello]
```

For the `Foo` class above:

```
Foo.instance_methods(false)                 #=> [:bar]
Foo.singleton_class.instance_methods(false) #=> [:baz]
```

So technically, a class method is just an instance method defined on the class' singleton class.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, I understand those syntax. However, my questions is, when to use class method, when to use instance methods, can u explain the USE CASE

Comment: @quyetdc it depends on what makes more sense. Let's say you have a `User` class with a user instance `alice` and you want to implement a new method `age` to return the user's age. You could implement that as a class method and pass it the user as an argument: `User.age(alice)`. Or you could implement it as a instance method and call it like: `alice.age`. What makes more sense? On the other hand, if you want to create a new user instance `jerry`. Does it make sense to send that method to an instance, e.g. `jerry = alice.new` or would the class be a better receiver: `jerry = User.new`.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to read up on Ruby's instance and class methods.
But personally, I'd do

```
class Foo
  class << self
    def foobar
    end
  end
end
```

instead of

```
class Foo
  def self.foobar
  end
end
```

whenever I want to add some class level attributes, or make a method private etc as

```
class Foo
  private
  def self.foobar
  end
end
```

wouldn't work the same as

```
class Foo
  class << self
    private
    def foobar
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Here it's the distinction between instance and class methods, yes. But in general, the concept of "current self" goes deeper than that. It is very useful for one to grok it.

Comment: Step through that door and welcome to the world of the [Eigenclass](https://medium.com/@ethan.reid.roberts/rubys-anonymous-eigenclass-putting-the-ei-in-team-ebc1e8f8d668).

Comment: I didn't know we could define the access specifier with class << self
Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks. I also prefer using `class << self` instead of `self.method_name`

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, I understand those syntax. However, my questions is, when to use class method, when to use instance methods, can u explain the USE CASE